# Durandal View Model Activation Before Composition

Tags: knockout.js, single-page-application, durandal

In the activate() class of my model, I want to evaluate a boolean property of the model, this.isExpanded, and apply appropriate classes to my view (expanded/collapsed) before it is bound.

```
function (system, app, ko) {
  "use strict";
  var SomeSection = contentControl.extend({
    init: function () {
      this.myBase();
      this.app = app;
      this.categories = ko.observableArray();
      this.isExpanded = ko.observable(false);
    },
    activate: activate,
    getData: getData,
    initializeView: initializeView,
    attached: attached,
    validate: validate,
    getView: getView,
    expandAll: expandAll,
    collapseAll: collapseAll
  });

  return SomeSection;  

  function activate() {
     if (this.isExpanded) {
       this.expandAll();
     } else {
       this.collapseAll();
     }
  }

  function collapseAll() {
    var that = this;

    for (var i = 0; i < that.categories().length; i++) {
      $('#' + that.categories()[i].name.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '_')).removeClass('expand');
      $('#' + that.categories()[i].name.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '_')).addClass('collapse');
      $("[data-toggle^='collapse']").addClass('collapsed');
    }
  }

}
```

However, the classes are not always applied prior to binding. Should I be returning a promise from `activate()` that would ensure `collapseAll()` has run prior to completing Composition? If so, could someone help illustrate what this would look like?

Comment: Why don't you want to control the classes from your viewmodel?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the dictinction @RoyJ. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Use the css binding to control which classes and element has. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of one way to delay the composition of a view, and that's to dynamically switch the view using durandal's getView hook. The way I've gone about this in the past is to create an observable to track the activate code finishing, and then using that observable to trigger my view to switch from a dummy loading view to the 'real' view.

Ex:

```
getView = ko.computed(function(){
    return this.activateCompleted() ? 'MyView' : 'Loading'
})

function activate() {
     if (this.isExpanded) {
       this.expandAll();
     } else {
       this.collapseAll();
     }
     this.activateCompleted(true);
  }
```

Comment: Going to give this a try today.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to understand is that you cannot use the activate method to directly modify your view.  This is because the view is not composed when activate is invoked for the first time.
See the Durandal lifecycle documentation: http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Hooking-Lifecycle-Callbacks.html

So IF you want to use JQuery from within your viewmodel to control the view, you can only call it after both the activate and attached callbacks have been run.  (My opinion is that Durandal is lacking one lifecycle event that should be run when both attached and activate have been run).  You can of course do this your self by maintaining observable set to true when both those methods have been run.

However in your case the simplest and most natural way would be to use binding handler to control the collapsible class in your view.  In that case you can omit from your viewmodel the collapseAll() and expandAll() functions.
See: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-controlling-descendant-bindings.html and of course the standard CSS-binding like Roy J pointed out above: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html.

Also using JQuery for DOM manipulation in your viewmodel class should be avoided if you want to keep real separation of concerns between your view and viewmodel.